# Folder structure when using multiple domains with WordPress

Tags: multisite, domain, domain-mapping

I have 10 domain names and am thinking about using WordPress. Are the domains set up in separate folders with their subsequent pages? In other words, how are the domains and their subsequent pages kept separate within WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the questions (and it is possible I don't so some clarity would be nice). You have multiple domain names and you would like to run WordPress on them all.

You have two options here

1. Install multiple copies of WordPress (one for each domain) the
   folder structure of this method is entirely up to you/your server
   settings how multiple domains are handled.
2. [Install WordPress Multi-Site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) (or network) and likely the [MU Domain Mapping Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/) this will let you have one installation with multiple domain names. By default you will have a "main domain" and all plugins/themes will be shared with the option to turn them on/off  on a per account bases.  All sites will have a unique uploads folder in `blog.dir/#` (where `#` is the blog's ID. The sites will all share the same database with individual tables for each site on the network.

The method you choose really depends on what you are trying to do.

### Method 1

**Pros:**

- Each site lives on it's own and has it's own database
- If something breaks with one site it doesn't take down the network

**Cons:**

- Can be a pain to manage/upgrade
- Users/accounts can be harder to link as you are dealing with different servers

### Method 2

**Pros:**

- Super easy to mange/upgrade
- Everything is in one place
- Shared database makes connections between sites (such as customer/user info) easy

**Cons:**

- Can be hard to set up initially
- If something breaks all sites could crash
- All plugins/themes are linked (although individual access can be controlled)
- Some plugins/themes don't work with Multi-Site

**If anyone else has pros/cons please add them in the comments or edit this question**